# Corona SDK shooting relative to players rotation

Tags: lua, coronasdk

So I want to shoot a projectile straight, relative to the bikes rotation.
Here is my code:

```
function shootButton:touch(event)
    if event.phase == "began" then
        if G_fired == false then 
            local firePosX= bFrame.x +170
            local firePosY = bFrame.y -20

            bullet.y = firePosY
            bullet.x = firePosX   
            bullet:applyForce( 23000, 10, bullet.x, bullet.y ) -- 44000
            bullet.isVisible = true
            bullet.isBullet = true

            return true
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Your question is incomplete. Please provide more details. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291234/how-to-write-a-debugging-request

Comment: Use the Bikes rotation Angle to calculate the x and y components of the normalized vector that points where you would like to shoot.   Apply you force value using these x and y values.